# Cannot properly decrypt a file with crypto.createDecipheriv(). File size is 0 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt / decrypt a file using streams. I'm not sure how to do it properly. The decrypted file's size is `0 bytes`.

I couldn't find any proper info on how to encrypt/decrypt streams. All the modules and articles I found are using methods that are very outdated (they are using deprecated methods) and mostly show how to encrypt/decrypt `strings` not `files`

### UPDATE

- Apparently I only get 0 bytes files in some system directories (e.g. `/Desktop`, `C:/`, etc). How do I fix that? I'm going to run this code from within Electron app.
- Also, is this code that I'm running safe? Am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const fs = require('fs')

const path = 'C:/testImage'
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
const keyLength = 32
const password = '1234'
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(32)
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, keyLength)


function encrypt() {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)
  const input = fs.createReadStream(path + '.png')
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(path + '.enc')
  input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output)

  cipher.on('end', () => {
    console.log('encrypted');
    decrypt()
  })
}


function decrypt() {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)
  const input = fs.createReadStream(path + '.enc')
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(path + '_dec.png')
  input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output)
  
  decipher.on('end', () => {
    console.log('decrypted');
  })
}


encrypt()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script and it works. (https://ibb.co/4Jvv6v1)

Did you tried to execute the script as administrator on windows?

If you are using GitBash or PowerShell, run it as administrator and then:

```
node your-script.js
```

Comment: That's weird. Do you get the original file back? I tried running it with admin rights but I still get a file of 0 bytes in size back

Comment: Yes, I get correctly the image back decrypted and it is the same size of the original one. https://ibb.co/4Jvv6v1

Comment: Hmm, I tried putting the image to another directory and it works now, thanks for the tip! Though, I'm not sure what to do if I need to encrypt/decrypt a file that's located on desktop or some other problematic directory. I don't know why running it with admin rights doesn't solve the problem. Windows is weird

Comment: Yes, if you can work into a local directory on the Desktop it's better. Windows has a lot of security checks in C:\ directory. Glad to be helpful. Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to change:

This:
`decipher.on('end', () => {`

to this:
`output.on('finish', () => {`

And it works now.